# (SOLVED) Tcl - remap 2 lists into one

Tags: tcl

I have N lists, e.g. 2 lists like these: `{a {1 2 3}}` and `{b {4 5 6}}`.

I would like to remap the values to obtain this list:
`{{{a 1} {b 4}} {{a 2} {b 5}} {{a 3} {b 6}}}`

What would be a good algorithm to do the above by starting from 2 or more lists and if the number of the second part of each list can be variable, i.e. `{{a {1 2 3 4 5 .. n}}`?

I'm using Tcl 8.5 (which I can't upgrade).

Comment: You may find https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+14 and the following lesson helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea why you'd want that transform, but as far as I understand what you want this will do it:

```
proc weirdshuffle lists {
    set tags        {}
    set iterators   {}

    foreach l $lists {
        lassign $l tag vals
        lappend tags $tag
        lappend iterators $tag $vals
    }

    lmap {*}$iterators {
        lmap tag $tags {
            list $tag [set $tag]
        }
    }
}

proc weirdshuffle8.5 lists {
    set tags        {}
    set iterators   {}

    foreach l $lists {
        lassign $l tag vals
        lappend tags $tag
        lappend iterators $tag $vals
    }

    set res {}
    foreach {*}$iterators {
        set tmp {}
        foreach tag $tags {
            lappend tmp [list $tag [set $tag]]
        }
        lappend res $tmp
    }
    set res
}

puts [weirdshuffle8.5 {
    {a {1 2 3}}
    {b {4 5 6}}
    {c {7 8 9}}
}]
```

It's easier to follow what it's doing with the `lmap` version, but that command first appeared in Tcl 8.6, so `weirdshuffle8.5` is an implementation that handles the loop accumulators explicitly.

The core idea is to exploit the fact that `foreach` (and `lmap`) support multiple iterators over different value lists, and construct the list of iterators and lists, then run the `lmap` (or `foreach`) on those.

For the paranoid, it's important to realise that doing this will create (or overwrite) variables in `weirdshuffle` based on the values of the lists passed in, possibly breaking things if one of those clashes with the variables that proc uses.  At the cost of some visual clutter, that could be defended against by making them indexes in arrays:

```
proc weirdshuffle_safe lists {
    set tags        {}
    set iterators   {}

    foreach l $lists {
        lassign $l tag vals
        lappend tags t($tag) $tag
        lappend iterators t($tag) $vals
    }

    lmap {*}$iterators {
        lmap {tag name} $tags {
            list $name [set $tag]
        }
    }
}
```

This also defends against the more pathological cases where the iterator variables look like fully qualified variables in other namespaces:
`{::foo::bar {1 2 2}} {::global {4 5 6}}` which would otherwise be able to set arbitrary state outside of the proc callframe.  If you're not in control of those tag values (`a` and `b` in your example), then I'd use the `_safe` variant to be sure.

Comment: MAny thanks! this worked perfectly on 8.5

Comment: If you're interested, I did a bit more digging into this and came up with an approach that is about 4 times faster than this.  It's a bit off topic to post here so when I'm done writing it up I'll create a page on the Tcl wiki and link it in a comment here, so keep an eye out in the next few days if your use case is performance-sensitive (only really matters with large inputs)

Answer (score 2):

This handles arbitrary numbers of lists, as well as sublists being of different lengths:

```
# incoming data
set lists {{a {1 2 3}} {b {4 5 6}} {c {11 22}} {d {100 200 300 400}}}

# split into "labels" and "data"
foreach lst $lists {
    lappend labels [lindex $lst 0]
    lappend data [lindex $lst 1]
}

# find the length of the longest sublist
set maxlen [::tcl::mathfunc::max {*}[lmap d $data {llength $d}]]

# create the resulting matrix
set result [lrepeat [llength $labels] {}]
for {set i 0} {$i < $maxlen} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $labels]} {incr j} {
        lset result $i end+1 [list [lindex $labels $j] [lindex $data $j $i]]
    }
}
```

Examining the result:

```
puts $result
# => {{a 1} {b 4} {c 11} {d 100}} {{a 2} {b 5} {c 22} {d 200}} {{a 3} {b 6} {c {}} {d 300}} {{a {}} {b {}} {c {}} {d 400}}

# or more readably:
foreach res $result {puts [list $res]}
# => {{a 1} {b 4} {c 11} {d 100}}
# => {{a 2} {b 5} {c 22} {d 200}}
# => {{a 3} {b 6} {c {}} {d 300}}
# => {{a {}} {b {}} {c {}} {d 400}}
```

---

> unfortunately I can't move from 8.5 to 8.6 so lmap can't be used.

Fortunately `lmap` is straightforward to implement in 8.5 -- this implements the most barebones usage of lmap, iterating over one list one element at a time.

```
proc lmap {varname lst body} {
    upvar $varname var
    set result [list]
    foreach var $lst {
        lappend result [uplevel $body]
    }
    return $result
}

lmap foo {11 22 33} {expr {$foo * 2}}   ;# => 22 44 66
```

For more details: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/lmap

Comment: While of course I still prefer mine, yours is a bit faster :)

Comment: Hey are you the cyanogilvie from https://hub.docker.com/r/cyanogilvie/tcl ? I want to thank you for making that available! [I'm using it](https://github.com/exercism/tcl-test-runner/blob/main/Dockerfile) in the test-runner for the Tcl learning track at https://exercism.org

Comment: The same, though that was an early prototype and not maintained anymore I'm afraid.  It evolved into https://hub.docker.com/r/cyanogilvie/alpine-tcl (https://github.com/cyanogilvie/alpine-tcl), which is in production use at Ruby Lane, so it is actively maintained.  It's roughly a superset in terms of the included packages, except that jitc replaces critcl and tcc4tcl.  exercism.org looks like a cool project :)

Comment: Thanks it works as expected, unfortunately I can't move from 8.5 to 8.6 so lmap can't be used.